# Connect Apache Flink to Local MinIO defaults to hashmap

Tags: apache-flink, minio

```
Docker Compose:
Flink 1.17
Minio RELEASE.2023-08-09T23-30-22Z
```

Configuration flink-conf.yaml. I also added the plugin s3-fs-presto.jar in plugin directory as volume in my docker compose.

```
state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: s3://olabucket/checkpoints
state.checkpoint-storage: filesystem
state.backend.incremental: true
s3.access-key: CGB4G82I6GKZRDT9X3IS
s3.secret-key: 4icQJb+6NCAKXfIBtbCYXbPboC3DViwWc+8SUaCX
s3.endpoint: http://minio:9000
s3.path.style.access: true
```

But when I run my flink job locally, it defaulted to hashmap not rocksdb. I also could not see any checkpoints in my minIO. Is there anything I missed?

```
14:44:25,783 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - No state backend has been configured, using default (HashMap) org.apache.flink.runtime.state.hashmap.HashMapStateBackend@3755f208
14:44:25,783 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StateBackendLoader            [] - State backend loader loads the state backend as HashMapStateBackend
14:44:25,784 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster                 [] - Checkpoint storage is set to 'jobmanager'
```

Second option I did, is to set the configuration via code below, but it expects AWS S3 not my local minio server. Using code below.

```
    WARNING: Fail to retrieve token 
    com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.getToken(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:91)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:69)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:60)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:48)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:124)
```

Here is my code

```
       final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
       configuration.setString("s3.endpoint", "http://localhost:9000");
       configuration.setString("s3.access-key", "CGB4G82I6GKZRDT9X3IS");
       configuration.setString("s3.secret-key", "4icQJb+6NCAKXfIBtbCYXbPboC3DViwWc+8SUaCX");

       env.configure(configuration);
       env.setStateBackend(new EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend());
       env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointStorage("s3://olabucket/checkpoints");

       env.enableCheckpointing(30000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
       env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(3, Time.of(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
       env.getCheckpointConfig().setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1);
       env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(300000);


env.getCheckpointConfig().enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup
                    .RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```